# Best way to provide static (default) values

Tags: java, swing, awt, constants

What is the best way to provide static (final) values that my program can access as default values? What is most efficient, or best practice?
I'm using plain old Java with AWT/Swing.

I could imagine for example writing a class `Default` that only contains public constants that can then be accessed. Would you call that 'hard-coded'?

Another idea would be to provide the values in a resources file like in Android. But then I would need a mechanism that parses the file at compile time and generates classes for it. Does something like this exist for Java without Android SDK?

I'm interested in best practices and design patterns. Any recommendation on my question is welcome.

Comment: enums are a good choice for maintaining constants

Comment: @JunedAhsan ...except in situations similar to this one, when the constants are largely unrelated to each other.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight i don't think constants will be unrelated. But the user knows the best :-)

Comment: I would avoid using a single class to hold unrelated default values. It doesn't scale. Imagine the JDK using a single class to hold all the constants/default values of all the classes in the JDK. Put the constants in the class they belong to. Example:  the separator char for files is in the File class.

Comment: @JBNizet The answer depends on how unrelated the values are: if all the defaults relate to user application settings, a single class may work fine. The devil is, of course, in the details, so OP is the only one to know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could imagine for example writing a class `Default` that only contains public constants that can then be accessed. Would you call that 'hard-coded'?

Absolutely, this would be hard-coding. On the other hand, all last-chance defaults are necessarily hard-coded, so this is not a problem at all.

You could also create a map hard-coded defaults for the various variables that you may use, and read from that map when you need the default. This, however, does not let the compiler ensure that all constants that you reference do exist, which I think was the point of creating a class for the defaults in the first place.

I would go with your suggestion of the `Default` class, and use a static import of it for nice and readable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Usually constants belong with the class to which they pertain.  For instance:

```
public class Service {
    public static final int PORT = 8080;

    public static final int TIMEOUT = 10_000;

    public Service() {
        // ...
    }
}

public class AppWindow {
    public static final boolean CENTER_WINDOW = false;

    public static final int VISIBLE_LINES = 12;

    public AppWindow() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you want the constants to be configurable, the easiest way is to let them be definable as system properties:

```
public class Service {
    public static final int PORT = Math.max(1,
        Integer.getInteger("Service.port", 8080));

    public static final int TIMEOUT = Math.max(1,
        Integer.getInteger("Service.timeout", 10_000));
}

public class AppWindow {
    public static final boolean CENTER_WINDOW =
        Boolean.getBoolean("AppWindow.centerWindow");

    public static final int VISIBLE_LINES = Math.max(1,
        Integer.getInteger("AppWindow.visibleLines", 12));
}
```

If you want to give the user the ability to configure those defaults in a file, you can read them from a properties file, as long as it's done before any of the classes containing the constants are loaded:

```
Path userConfigFile =
    Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "MyApp.properties");

if (Files.isReadable(userConfigFile)) {
    Properties userConfig = new Properties();
    try (InputStream stream =
            new BufferedInputStream(Files.newInputStream(userConfigFile))) {
        userConfig.load(stream);
    }

    Properties systemProperties = System.getProperties();
    systemProperties.putAll(userConfig);
    System.setProperties(systemProperties);
}
```

(I have deliberately oversimplified the location of the properties file for brevity; each OS has a different policy regarding the location of such files.)